# NLog code line logging

Tags: nlog

I am using NLog to log error messages into csv:

```
<target name="csv" xsi:type="File" 
                fileName="${basedir}/Logs/log.csv"
                archiveFileName="${basedir}/Logs/Archives/log.{#####}.csv"
                archiveAboveSize="10240"
                archiveNumbering="Sequence"
                concurrentWrites="true"
                keepFileOpen="false">
            <layout xsi:type="CSVLayout" delimiter="Comma" withHeader="false">
              <column name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
              <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
              <column name="logger" layout="${logger}"/>
              <column name="level" layout="${level}"/>
            </layout>
        </target>
```

How can I add a column to track the code line number?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [${callsite}](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Callsite-Layout-Renderer) layout renderer.

```
<column name="source" layout="${callsite:fileName=true}" />
```

Comment: The link is broken, information can now be found at https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#layouts-and-layout-renderers